# How to update lua package on ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lua

When i try ./configure i got this :

> checking for LUA... configure: error:
>   Package requirements (lua >= 5.1.3)
>   were not met:
>
> Requested 'lua >= 5.1.3' but version of Lua is 5.1.2

So i try to update lua with remove and new install but still does not work

> ~/lsyncd-2.0.3# lua -v Lua 5.1.2 
>   Copyright (C) 1994-2007 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

How can i update the package to 5.1.4 ?

(I am on ubuntu 8.04)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

8.04 is pretty old in Ubuntu years.  If Lua 5.1.3 or 5.1.4 don't show up on synaptic ("package manageer"), then chances are that they have not been backported to 8.04.  The best remedy would be for you to upgrade your Ubuntu system to the latest LTS version, which is 10.04 Lucid Lynx.  There should be an option or button on your update manager or package manager.

The newer Ubuntu will provide a recent Lua.

Comment: Latest LTS is 10.04 Lucid Lynx.